# Where to find Angular 2 discontinued keywords?

Tags: angular

While going trough different Angular 2 tutorials I have noticed that some keywords do not exist any more (e.g. @View, TemplateConfig ...).

Is there one central place where I can find what are the keywords and what are replacements for those?

I have tried googling but I have not found anything useful...

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the changelog and issues daily since it is still in beta :
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

When a new version comes they write it on the breaking changes section (which will break your code!). Even if they forget to write it people write it on the issues section so that you can track the forgotten changes from there.

Comment: Is there anything more user friendly?
I have seen that but is just a pile of things, no structure ... There are too many source examples of Angular2 from 2015 with now non existing keywords ...

Comment: @Mr.Smith well yes it contains a lot of info but it is doing what you asked. It shows all of the changes :) Besides you can't guarantee for example we will be using component tag tomorrow. But if you check it daily you will know. The other articles people have written as you say contains a lot of outdated syntax and info. And the only way to keep yourself up-to-date is the changelog and the official documentation.